# Using scikit learn spectral clustering with precomputed affinity matrix?

Tags: python-2.7, cluster-computing, scikit-learn

Got a precomputed similarity matrix `Sim` where `s_ij` equals the similarity between vector `i` and vector `j`.

Trying to compute clusters.
Doing

```
  clustering = SpectralClustering(cluster_count, affinity='precomputed', eigen_solver='arpack')
  clustering.fit(sparse_dok_sim_matrix)
  clusters = clustering.fit_predict(sparse_dok_sim_matrix)
  print clusters
```

I am getting something that looks like cluster labels but is completely false. The weight of the edges between samples in the same cluster is 99% of the weight of edges on the graph. The clustering result appears to be completely random and meaningless.

Any advice, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

For instance I attempted this with dbscan and got nothing:

```
results = block_diag(np.ones((3,3)), np.ones((3,3)), np.ones((4,4)))
results = 1000 * (np.ones((len(results), len(results))) - results)
print results
print dbscan(X=results.astype(float), metric='precomputed')
```

This was the result, it said everything is noise even though it's clear the first three points are in the same spot and so are the next three points... The last four as well.

```
[[    0.     0.     0.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.]
 [    0.     0.     0.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.]
 [    0.     0.     0.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.]
 [ 1000.  1000.  1000.     0.     0.     0.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.]
 [ 1000.  1000.  1000.     0.     0.     0.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.]
 [ 1000.  1000.  1000.     0.     0.     0.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.]
 [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]
(array([], dtype=int64), array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DBSCAN: according to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.dbscan.html#sklearn.cluster.dbscan), the `min_samples=5` by default. None of your "clusters" has 5 samples, so everything is labelled as noise.
For the SpectralClustering I can't help you without more details.

Comment: The last one has four.

Comment: Thanks!! Is there any way I could hmm... use a sparse matrix with dbscan?

Comment: yes: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.dbscan.html#sklearn.cluster.dbscan

Comment: Hi, I read that. What I'm wondering is what is the distance when no distance is specified by the precomputed sparse matrix? Is an unspecified distance infinity or zero? Or is it supposed to be defined somehow inside the sparse matrix object?

Comment: They are assumed zero. Which seems odd thinking about it. But I think the sparse input is more meant for X being features, not similarities.